# Hibernate returning Proxy for previously loaded entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I am getting entity proxy instead the real entity when I load from db an instance previously loaded.

The first time I load the instance is through a method thtat executes this code

```
getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList().get(0)
```

The second time the application executes this method

```
public T findById(Long id) {
    DetachedCriteria crit = DetachedCriteria.forClass(entityClass).add(
        Property.forName(IdentifiableEntity.ID_PROPERTY).eq(id));
    Criteria executableCriteria = getExecutableCriteria(crit);
    return (T) executableCriteria.uniqueResult();
}
```

When I call `findById` with an id for a entity already loaded then I get a entity proxy. But if call the function to get a new entity (not already loaded) then I get the real entity.

I don´t understand this behavioura and I have no idea where the problem could be.

This is important for me because a hierarchy of entities is defined and the code executes for parent entity class, not the child one. Then when I get the parent entity proxy the methods of entity child does not exist

Regards

Comment: That's expected. You shouldn't care if it's a proxy or not. Just don't use instanceof, and don't cast your entity to a subclass, and everything should go fine. Use OO. Define abstract method in the base class and override them in the subclass. Or use the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the unproxy version you could simply do this:

```
Object unproxied = ((SessionImplementor)session).getPersistenceContext().unproxy(proxy);
```

Comment: This seems to work at first, all props where loaded normally but the first time i try to use the unproxied entity I get this error `object was an uninitialized proxy for`. When I try `HibernateProxy hibernateProxy=(HibernateProxy) proxy; LazyInitializer initializer=hibernateProxy.getHibernateLazyInitializer(); MyEntity unproxiedCampaign=(MyEntity) initializer.getImplementation();` I get the entity with some props loaded as `persistentBag` which seems to work fine afterwards. What are the difference of the 2 approaches and why could this be happening only in parts of the app for an entity?